# Looping through all XML elements and append the XML file based on the input from a text file

Tags: xml, vbscript

I want to iterate through all the elements in an XML file and assign the values to the elements through a text file.

`project_template.xml`:

```xml
<project baseDir="" outputDir="">
  <rule inherit="" preset="" pattern=""  /> 
</project>
```

`test.txt`:

```
baseDir="test1"
outputDir="test2"
inherit="test3"
preset="test4"
pattern="true"
```

`Project.vbs`:

```vb
Option Explicit 
Dim arrFileLines(), final(45)
Dim i, objFSO, objFile, l, index, finalString
i = 0

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\1021752\Desktop\project\test.txt", 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  ReDim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
  arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
  i = i + 1
Loop
objFile.Close

Const NODE_ELEMENT = 1
Const CONFUSER_NS = "http://confuser.codeplex.com"

Dim doc, moduleElem, args, arg

Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set doc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

doc.Async = False
doc.Load "project_template.xml"

If doc.ParseError.ErrorCode Then
  WScript.Echo doc.ParseError
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

For l = LBound(arrFileLines) To UBound(arrFileLines) Step 1
  index = InStr(1, arrFileLines(l), "=")
  final(l) = Right(arrFileLines(l), Len(arrFileLines(l)) - index)
Next
doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute "baseDir", final(0)    'here I am manually assigning the value to the "baseDir"
doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute "outputDir", final(1) 
doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute "inherit", final(2)
doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute "preset", final(3)
doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute "pattern", final(4)
doc.Save "project.xml"
```

Desired output:

```xml
<project baseDir="test1" outputDir="test2" >
  <rule inherit="test3" preset="test4" pattern="true"  />
</project>
```

I want the code to iterate through all the elements in the XML file and return the names.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading your parameters file into a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4.aspx):

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\1021752\Desktop\project\test.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  arr = Split(f.ReadLine, "=", 2)
  d(arr(0)) = Replace(arr(1), """", "")
Loop
f.Close
```

Also, your code would add all attributes to the root node of the XML data instead of updating the attributes of each individual node. What you need is a recursive procedure that updates the attributes present in the current node, then does the same for all of its child nodes:

```vb
Sub UpdateAttributes(node, values)
  For Each attr In node.Attributes
    If values.Exists(attr.Name) Then node.SetAttribute attr.Name, values(attr.Name)
  Next

  For Each child In node.ChildNodes
    UpdateAttributes child, values
  Next
End Sub
```

Invoke the procedure with the XML root node and your dictionary:

```vb
UpdateAttributes doc.DocumentElement, d
```

Comment: I changed the code a bit, I removed the If statement `Sub UpdateAttributes(node, values)
  For Each attr In node.Attributes
    node.SetAttribute attr, values(attr)
  Next

  For Each child In node.ChildNodes
    UpdateAttributes child, values
  Next
End Sub` when I implement this method and run it,  it is throwing a type mismatch error 800A000D. Can you help  me in resolving it as I didn't find any solution

Comment: You need to use `attr.Name`, not just `attr`. See updated answer.